# nodejs variable only in function and sub-functions

Tags: javascript, node.js, variables, scope

I'm trying to run the same function multiple times at once but if I create a local one with `var variablename` the sub-functions dont recognize it. And if I make it global, all instances of the Function will overwrite it.

```
function vladimir(){
var test="hello";
hanspeter();
}
function hanspeter(){
console.log(test);
}
```

console.log outputs undefined.

Comment: `hanspeter()` does not become a *sub-function* just because it is called from `vladimir()`. You need to *define* it inside `vladimir()`

Comment: @techfoobar To be fair, his expectation describes dynamic scoping, which is used in some (mostly older) languages - APL, older Lisps, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're running into a scoping issue here.

When you declare methods without using var (`function <function_name>() {}`), those function declarations are moved to the top of the local scope (called function hoisting, if you want to look it up).

If you manually declare you functions, you have to wait until they are both declared before you can use them.  This is because the first function won't know about any functions declared under it.

You've also got an issue where variables aren't being scoped.  If you have a variable that you declare in one function, it isn't guaranteed to be there in another (since it is a different scope).

If you want to pass these variables around, the easiest way is to pass these into the function parameters, which will be reachable in your other function.

So in your simple example, you could get it to work like this:

```
var hanspeter = function (test) {
  console.log(test);
}

var vladimir = function() {
  hanspeter( "hello" );
}
```

Comment: "those function declarations are moved to the top of the file" - this is not true; they are moved to the top of the _scope_, which is an important distinction.  It is also irrelevant to the question; the code as posted is not affected by function hoisting - it will behave the same if the functions are declared like `var hanspeter = function(){...}`.

Comment: @AaronDufour You're correct, top of the scope, that was my fault. I figured he was running into issues declaring his functions with his statement: "I'm trying to run the same function multiple times at once but if I create a local one with var variablename the sub-functions dont recognize it. And if I make it global, all instances of the Function will overwrite it."  Might be wrong, just figured I would give a bit of an overview of what could be going wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Use function arguments:

```
function vladimir(){
    var test="hello";
    hanspeter(test);
}
function hanspeter(arg){
    console.log(arg);
}
```

https://learn.jquery.com/javascript-101/functions/

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript uses lexical scoping - it looks like you're expecting dynamic scoping.  Essentially what this means is that a function has access to variables based on where it is declared, not where it is called.  For example, the following would work:

```
function vladimir(){
  var test="hello";
  function hanspeter(){
    console.log(test);
  }
  hanspeter();
}
```

Because `test` exists where `hanspeter` is declared.  But in yours, `test` exists where `hanspeter` is *called*, which does not give it access.

You can also get variables by passing them:

```
function vladimir(){
  var test="hello";
  hanspeter(test);
}
function hanspeter(test2){
  console.log(test2);
}
```

I called the argument to `hanspeter` `test2` to show that it is the argument's name that matters, not the name of the variable being passed.